# Blazor Client-Side (WebAssembly) reading a json file on startup.cs

Tags: blazor

Since `appsettings.json` does not work very well with  blazor WA, i am creating my own and putting a `.json` file in `wwwroot`, in the pages that require it, i use the `HttpClient` to get to the file as follow
`config = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Configuration>("/config/appsettings.json");`

This works great, however I am doing this in multiple pages, so I would like to inject `Configuration` object/service at startup.cs and have my pages use that instead of doing this multiple times.

I am having a hard time finding out how to properly read the file in Startup.cs, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It seems that `App.OnInitializedAsync` is being fired before `Index.OnInitializedAsync` but the `Settings = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Settings>("/config/appsettings.json").ConfigureAwait(false);` taking longer which is causing `App.OnInitializedAsync` to execute BEFORE the above line.

here is all the code

Startup.cs

```cs
    public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ConfigurationManager>();
            services.AddBlazoredToast();
        }
        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }

    }
```

App.razor

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("App.OnInitializedAsync");
        await configManager.InitializeAsync();

    }
```

Index.razor

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index.OnInitializedAsync");


        //config = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Configuration>("/config/appsettings.json");
        if (configManager == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Index.OnInitializedAsync config manager is null");
        }
        else
        {
            if (configManager.Settings == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index.OnInitializedAsync config.Settings is null");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("base url" + configManager.Settings.ApiBaseUrl);

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the sequence

```
WASM: App.OnInitializedAsync
WASM: ConfigurationManager.InitializeAsync
WASM: Index.OnInitializedAsync
WASM: Index.OnInitializedAsync config.Settings is null
WASM: ConfigurationManager.Setting has been set: ApiBaseUrl https://localhost:44316
```

Comment: Try these links: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1152 https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12614 https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5531

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way IMHO is to register a singleton `Task`

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddSingleton(async p =>
                {
                    var httpClient = p.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
                    Console.WriteLine("Get settings called");
                    return await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Settings>("settings.json")
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
                });
        }
```

And call in with async where you need settings. In page for sample

```cs
@inject Task<Settings> _getSettings

...

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var settings = await _getSettings;
        Console.WriteLine("Settings received in main {0}", settings?.ApiBaseUrl);
    }
}
```

This way the call to **settings.json** is made just once

Comment: Test it as well, it works like a charm, simple, elegant and easy to use, awesome work, thank you

Comment: Thank you.  This needs the pre-release (as of June 2020) package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient to get access to the GetJsonAsync method.